# How shall I use card-group with ngFor?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, card

**This is the basic syntax of card-group**

```
<div class="card-group">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" [src]="getImage(1)" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" [src]="getImage(3)" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**The above shows, card-gruop of two cards**

**Now I want is to use ngFor , to make grid of cards I have. I am want it to be done with bootstrap, no angular material.**

**Here is my ts file, here I have a observable, called products$, as follows**

```
export interface Product{
    id?:string,
    name:string,
    price:string;
    quantity:string;
    tags:Tags[];
    description:string;
    files: File[];
}
products$:Observable<Product[]>
  getImage(id:any){
    return "http://localhost:5000/getImage/"+id

  }
```

**I want in my html page to be like something as it follow.**

```
<div class="card-group">
   <div *ngFor = "let p of products$ | async">
       <div class="card">
        <img
        [src]="getImage(p.id)"
          class="card-img-top"
          alt="..."
        />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{p.name}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the 
            bulk of the
            card's content.
          </p>
          <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**But this thing does not work.Kindly, please tell me how to do this.**

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<div class="card-group">
  <ng-container *ngIf= "products$ | async as product">
   <div *ngFor="let p of product">
       <div class="card">
        <img
        [src]="getImage(p.id)"
          class="card-img-top"
          alt="..."
        />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{p.name}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the 
            bulk of the
            card's content.
          </p>
          <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked the values of product in the template using iterpolation?

Comment: Yes I have. Thanks for your help. I came up with the solution.